# JSON unmarshalling with Moxy in ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I'm using Moxy in my Jersey (2.7) project basically just to marshall my objects to JSON when the service issues a response. It works fine, but now I am also using ContainerResponseFilter to make some changes on every response issued and I am not sure how to unmarshall the content of the request body into an object, which is something I need.

Specifically:

- i've just registered Moxy in a `ResourceConfig` instance: `register(MOXyJsonProvider.class)`
- a class is using JAXB annotations, so when I set an instance of the class in Response.entity() it gets transformed into JSON properly
- the request body (also JSON) also gets unmarshalled into an object when I set it as a method paramether, for instance:

  `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getSomething( MyClass instance ) {`

However inside a ContainerResponseFilter I can access the request body like so,

`InputStream body = requestContext.getEntityStream()`

but I'm not sure if it's possible to have this also automatically converted into an object. The information I need is relatively simple, so I guess I could parse JSON in another way, but I'm curious.

I've tried searching, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ContainerReponseFilter, you can do something like this:

```
public class ApplicationResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext request,
        final ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {

        // your code
        response.getEntity();

    }
}
```

which converts it to your object with JAXB annotations. I was not doing it in my responseFilter, but I've just debugged it and it works.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing and actually it helps me, so thanks a lot. I forgot I already had the object in my response, long day yesterday. But generally do you know if it's however possible to unmarshall an InputStream from the request body?

Comment: sorry, you meant the request in the first place, and I answered you about the response. I don't think you can unmarshall it easily in the responseFilter. I've been debugging a bit and looking at the stack and I did not find an easy way. But, what info you need from the request? You could add a requestFilter and put information in the request context. You have available requestContext.setSecurityContext(...) but also requestContext.setProperty(...)

Comment: There is some information in the request I want to send back to the user. But in the cases I need it, it's already in the response, so that works fine. Thanks again for your help.